# How can I find all options with a list of values using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to find and hide multiple options in select menu.

Here is my menu

```
<select class="form-control" name="settingsColumnAggregate" id="settingsColumnAggregate">
    <option value="None" selected="">None</option>
    <option value="Sum">Sum</option>
    <option value="Avg">Avg</option>
    <option value="Count">Count Distinct</option>
    <option value="Max">Max</option>
    <option value="Min">Min</option>
</select>
```

I want to hide the options where the value is in `["Sum","Ave","Max","Min"]`

Here is what I tried

```
$('#settingsColumnAggregate')
.find('option[value="Sum"][value="Avg"][value="Max"][value="Min"]')
.hide();
```

But that is not working.

How can I correctly select multiple options by a list of values?
Here is what I tried

Comment: Use the [Multiple selector](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)  `option[value="Sum"], option[value="Avg"]`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to loop through all the option or use `filters()`

```js
var arr = ["Sum","Avg","Max","Min"];
$('#settingsColumnAggregate option').filter(function(){
    return jQuery.inArray( this.value, arr ) !== -1
}).hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" name="settingsColumnAggregate" id="settingsColumnAggregate">
    <option value="None" selected="">None</option>
    <option value="Sum">Sum</option>
    <option value="Avg">Avg</option>
    <option value="Count">Count Distinct</option>
    <option value="Max">Max</option>
    <option value="Min">Min</option>
</select>
```

Or use `find` and multiple selector which is bit messy though and hard to read. You forgot to add `,` in your code which treats it as single selector.

```
$('#settingsColumnAggregate')
.find('option[value="Sum"],option[value="Avg"],option[value="Max"],option[value="Min"]')
.hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query is all wrong, you are trying to select an element `option` with the attribute `value` equal to `Sum`, equal to `Avg`, equal to `Max` and equal to `Min` at the same time, this doesn't event exist, i think. So, your query need to be like this:

```
$('#settingsColumnAggregate')
.find('option[value="Sum"], option[value="Avg"], option[value="Max"], option[value="Min"]')
.hide();
```

Note that i've separated every option with a coma.

You can read the documentation on [How to write selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)